# При валидации резко падает точность по сравнению с тренировкой нейронной сети

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, машинное-зрение

Есть архитектура сети для разпознования двух отпечатков стоп на изображении. Весь набор данных очень похож. Просто разные размеры стоп немного в разном положении. Я хочу их определить. Для этого беру сверточную чать потом развожу ее на 2 полносвязных с 4мя выходами и объединяю в один выходной слой.[image: структура сети].
В качестве функции потерь **mse**, а метрики собтвенная IoU, являющаяся средним значением двух областей(стоп).
В процессе обучения единственной эпохи я получаю достойные результаты[image: начало эпохи]
[image: конец эпохи]. Так как эпоха одна, то о переобучении речи быть не может.Т.к. изображения используются всего по 1 раз. Логично что при валидации (10% от обучающей выборки) должны быть сопоставимые результаты. Но я получаю [image: валидационная выборка] и с тестовыми изображениями таже ситуация. Это противоречит всему моему пониманию процесса. Объясните в чем может быть проблема. Какой код нужно прикрепить? Очень нуждаюсь в помощи. Я в тупике!
[image: тестирование]

Comment: 1. в валидации участвуют данные, не попавшие в тренировку, поэтому качество всегда хуже, чем меньше данных. 2. соотв., у вас мало данных для тренировки. 3. можно добавить искуственных данных - стопы с поворотом, например, со смещением влево-вправо-вверх-вниз

Comment: Если я за 1 эпоху получаю результат указанный выше, то значит данных достаточно. Ведь я не повторяю обучение на одной и той же картинке несколько раз. В каждом батче в рамках одной эпохи входные данные не повторяются. Или я что-то не правильно понимаю? А также это не зависит от размера валидации. Если я ставлю 10% то все что тренирует показывает норм, а валидационный процесс также плох. При 20% та же картина.

Comment: при тренировке сети, условно, вы можете получить результат даже на двух-трех картинках, но результат понимаете же. никакой. так и тут, если разброс существенно высок, то можно сделать вывод, что набор данных для тренировки ограничен и его следует увеличить. у меня нет чёткого представления и не встречал о взаимосвязи величины тренировочного набора для обработки изображений, но он есть. можете сравнить свой набор с типичными доступными базами например для yolo

Comment: вот данные по coco dataset



    Сегментация объектов
    Признание в контексте
    Сегментация суперпиксельного материала
    330 тыс. изображений (> 200 тыс. с метками)
    1,5 миллиона экземпляров объектов
    80 категорий объектов
    91 категория вещей
    5 подписей к изображению
    250 000 человек с ключевыми точками

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт. В данном случае такой сильный эффект давал 20% Dropout в сверточной части в совокупности с небольшим количеством эпох. В полносвязной части этот эффект также заметен, но гораздо меньше. Есть еще над чем работать, но идея понятна.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]